# How to display a changed db row on the listings page after form submit, when the listings page pulls from a db that is updated every 10 minutes?

Tags: mysql, caching, solr

I have a listings page which is built from a query to a query data store (EG: solr) that is updated (in bulk) every 10 minutes from the primary (relational) database.

When a user clicks on 'edit' for a row (or clicks on 'create' to create a new row), after he submits the edit/create form, the row in the primary database is updated in real-time, but the query data store (EG: solr) is not updated for up to another 10 minutes.

The problem I have is that the listings page would still be displaying the stale result set (updated 10 minutes ago), so the user may not see his changed row for up to another 10 minutes.

Is there a way I can ensure that the user will be able to see his changes in real-time, even though the listings page continues to query from the query data store (EG: solr)?

Comment: The solution is to update the solr data store immediately after a user adds/updates the item in question. You don't need to do a bulk update, just an update for the one row the user changed. You haven't posted what library you are using to interface with solr, or any of your application code, so it's impossible for me to post a specific example showing how to do this.

Comment: The problem with updating solr each time after the row has changed is that it would require a commit to be issued to solr 3.3 (or a 'soft commit' once near-real-time search is implemented in solr 4.0, which is as yet unreleased), both of which would decrease performance (http://blog.raspberry.nl/2011/04/08/solr-update-performance/). As a result, I am looking for a way to ensure that the changed row shows up in the listing page immediately after the user submits the form without having to immediately update solr after the row changes.

Comment: you are probably unnecessarily pre-optimizing. Even the in the slowest benchmark in that link, it was 18 documents commits per second. And in your case, unless you also have eight million rows, it will be much faster than 18 documents per second, which is already fast enough as to be a non-consideration for most applications. Just go ahead and run the single commit immediately after the user makes a change. See if it noticeably affects the speed of your application at all. I suspect it won't. And it's scalable to nearly any real-world use case as well.

Comment: The problem isn't with the indexing speed (18 docs/sec versus 90 docs/sec), both of which are probably sufficient. Instead, the problem is with the search query performance while commits are occurring (http://engineering.socialcast.com/2011/05/realtime-search-solr-vs-elasticsearch/). Solr's querying performance drops significantly when commits are made (especially for faceting queries since they depend on the solr query cache but when a commit occurs, the cache is invalidated.